# How can I combine these two code examples - splitting excel workbook and removing speech marks from csv

Tags: excel, vba

Firstly, really sorry I am very new to vba and know that this will be a really basic question for a lot of people here but I am trying to learn.

I am trying to split an excel file down into seperate csv files based on the first block of code I have taken from this site.

I am also trying to run the second block of code somewhere within the first block to open the csv files and remove the "" it puts in there.

Both bits of code work seperately but I do not have the knowledge or skill to join them together. I have tried for over a day but bits like:

```
wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Prefix & "_" & WorkbookCounter
```

In the first block of code and trying to replace it with this:

```
xName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("C:\Users\trd836c3\Desktop\PO creation files\Files for upload testing\" & "Purchase" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmddhhmmss"), "CSV File (*.csv), *.csv")
```

or any combination of it just do not work.

This is the code to split an excel file down from LuH on here, but it saves as an excel file, and I cannot work out how to change it to a csv with a YYYYMMDDHHMMSS filename.

```
Sub Test()
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim ThisSheet As Worksheet
  Dim NumOfColumns As Integer
  Dim RangeToCopy As Range
  Dim WorkbookCounter As Integer
  Dim RowsInFile
  Dim Prefix As String

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  'Initialize data
  Set ThisSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
  NumOfColumns = ThisSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
  WorkbookCounter = 1
  RowsInFile = 100     'how many rows (incl. header) in new files?
  Prefix = "test"      

  For p = 1 To ThisSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count Step RowsInFile
  Set wb = Workbooks.Add

 'Paste the chunk of rows for this file
 Set RangeToCopy = ThisSheet.Range(ThisSheet.Cells(p, 1),ThisSheet.Cells(p + RowsInFile - 1, NumOfColumns))
 RangeToCopy.Copy wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1")

'Save the new workbook, and close it
 wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Prefix & "_" & WorkbookCounter
 wb.Close

'Increment file counter
 WorkbookCounter = WorkbookCounter + 1
 Next p

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

This code creates a csv file with the working file name, and removing speech marks, but I cannot get this to automatically break an excel file into individual csv files of 10 rows.

```
Sub Export()
'updateby Extendoffice 20160530
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xRow As Range
Dim xCell As Range
Dim xStr As String
Dim xTxt As String
Dim xName As Variant
On Error Resume Next
If ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Count > 1 Then
  xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.AddressLocal
Else
  xTxt = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AddressLocal
End If
Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select data range:", "Kutools for Excel", xTxt, , , , , 8)
If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
xName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("C:\Users\trd836c3\Desktop\PO creation files\Files for upload testing\" & "Purchase" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmddhhmmss"), "CSV File (*.csv), *.csv")
Open xName For Output As #1
For Each xRow In xRg.Rows
    xStr = ""
    For Each xCell In xRow.Cells
        xStr = xStr & xCell.Value & Chr(9)
    Next
    While Right(xStr, 1) = Chr(9)
        xStr = Left(xStr, Len(xStr) - 1)
    Wend
    Print #1, xStr
Next
Close #1
If Err = 0 Then MsgBox "The file has saved to: " & xName, vbInformation,      "Kutools for Excel"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your requirement correctly, below code will give you the result

```
Sub Test()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ThisSheet As Worksheet
Dim NumOfColumns As Integer
Dim RangeToCopy As Range
Dim WorkbookCounter As Integer
Dim RowsInFile
Dim Prefix As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Initialize data
Set ThisSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
NumOfColumns = ThisSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
WorkbookCounter = 1
RowsInFile = 100     'how many rows (incl. header) in new files?
Prefix = "test"

For p = 1 To ThisSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count Step RowsInFile

    'Paste the chunk of rows for this file
    Set RangeToCopy = ThisSheet.Range(ThisSheet.Cells(p, 1), ThisSheet.Cells(p + 
RowsInFile - 1, NumOfColumns))

    xName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Prefix & "_" & WorkbookCounter & ".csv"
    Open xName For Output As #1
    For Each xRow In RangeToCopy.Rows
        xStr = ""
        For Each xCell In xRow.Cells
            xStr = xStr & xCell.Value & Chr(9)
        Next
        While Right(xStr, 1) = Chr(9)
            xStr = Left(xStr, Len(xStr) - 1)
        Wend
        Print #1, xStr
    Next
    Close #1

    'Increment file counter
    WorkbookCounter = WorkbookCounter + 1
Next p

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set wb = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you so much! Now to work out what you did!

Comment: @MattBarnes glad to hear that. will you accept the answer.